# Object’s Parent Current Instance

Tags: c#, object, instance, parent

Having the following object(s):

```
public class Employee
{
    public string LastName { get; set; } = "";

    internal class SubordinateList<T> : List<T>, IPublicList<T> where T : Employee
    {
        public new void Add(T Subordinate)    {    }
    }
    public IPublicList<Employee> Subordinates = new SubordinateList<Employee>();
}
```

The SubordinateList object is inside the Employee object making Employee the parent of SubordinateList in a certain way.

If we put this code below:

```
Anakin = New Employee();
Luke = New Employee();
Anakin.Subordinates.Add(Luke);
```

The third line will trigger the method “Add” of SubordinateList.
I would like to get the Current Instance for the Parent of SubordinateList  like this:

```
public new void Add(T Subordinate)
{
    T Manager = Subordinate.ParentInstance;

    // then it will be possible to see the current value of
    // the property "LastName" for Anakin with "Manager.LastName"
}
```

Comment: `No use of the constructors with some parameters to link the objects` Why do you have that constraint?

Comment: The project is a framework for developpers. Being forced to pass a parameter for the constructor is not convenient and not really elegant.

Comment: What is *really* not elegant is storing dates and times as string

Comment: this is for Import process from external system where data exchange through SOA are string. After it will be converted properly.

Comment: Are all the clients (and the server) of the "data exchange through SOA [as] string" in the same time zone?  You need to be very careful if you want to have it "be converted properly".  Dates and Times are hard.  Using strings as your persistent mechanism for dates and times is even harder.  Schedule in time for some rework on this.  It's **_very_** hard to get this right in one try.

Comment: Very much indeed. I am expert on that matter. But the first step to get the data from XML, JSON and others is to receive them as string. Besides, these comments regarding how to store data are not related to this topic. Thank you.

Comment: What's the point of making `SubordinateList` generic and restricting it to `Employee`?

Comment: Hello Brian. I agree with you this looks a bit odd by having a generic object restricted to one type only. The fact is that 'SubordinateList' must be inherited from 'List<T>' which is generic. And if T would be completely unknow, we could not code something like 'if (!Exists(x => (x.FirstName == Superior.FirstName) && (...))' since T alone is not aware of the definition of 'FirstName'.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way since you don't have a reference to the manager. This is how I would implement it:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = "";
    public string LastName { get; set; } = "";
    public string HiredDate { get; set; } = "";

    private List<Employee> _subordinates = new List<Employee>();
    public ReadOnlyCollection<Employee> Subordinates => _subordinates.AsReadOnly();

    public void AddSubordinate(Employee employee)
    {
        _subordinates.Add(Employee);
        //the manager is 'this'
        var managerLastName = this.LastName;
     }
}
```

Exposing the subordinate list as a `ReadOnlyCollection` allows other classes to read the list, but prevents them from updating the list directly. So only the `AddSubordinate()` method can be used to add employees, where you can do what you need with the manager's information.

Comment: You've read my mind. This is exactly the approach I use presently. But, still, I dream about something like "Subordinates.Add". Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The problem with making your own subordinate list class is that you lose the reference to the manager.

Comment: Unless you take a reference in the constructor of your list, so you can declare it like this: `public IPublicList<Employee> Subordinates = new SubordinateList<Employee>(this);`. Then the constructor stores that as a private field.

Comment: I am aware of this. But I don't want to take this path.

Comment: That's fine. Then you need to keep the "adding" logic in the `Employee` class itself.